# Parent and child relations in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm having some issues with parsing refs to child classes using ReactJS
Here is my main class where all my refs are located :

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Title content="I am Tristan Vermeesch" />
        <hr />
        <Bio />
        <Introduction ref={(Introduction) => { this.introref = Introduction; }} />
        <Timeline ref={(Timeline) => { this.timelineref = Timeline }} />
        <Projects ref={(Projects) => { this.projectsref = Projects }} />
        <Skills ref={(Skills) => { this.skillsref = Skills }} />
        <Certificates ref={(Certificates) => { this.certifref = Certificates }} />
        <Download ref={(Download) => { this.downloadref = Download }} />
        <Contact ref={(Contact) => { this.contactref = Contact }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want that a Child component in my `<Navbar />` retrieves the ref to make it scroll down using `react-scroll-to-component`. Here is my Navbar class :

```
class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navbar" >
                <Route path="/textversion" component={TextVersion} />
                <Navitem dName={"Text Version"} url={"textversion"} />
                <Navitem dName={"Contact"} url={"contact"} />
                <Navitem dName={"Resume"} url={"resume"} />
                <Navitem dName={"Certificates"} url={"certificates"} />
                <Navitem dName={"Skills"} url={"skills"} onClick={() => scrollToComponent(this.skillsref, { duration: 1600 })} />
                <Navitem dName={"Projects"} url={"projects"} />
                <Navitem dName={"Life"} url={"life"} />
                <Navitem dName={"Me"} url={"me"} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

You can see the onclick function there, it works in the main class but how can I get all the refs from the parent class?

Comment: I'm also new in react ... but can you try to pass from your App class this.skillsref as props at your NavBar like <Navbar  skillsref= this.skillsref/> so you can use inside Navbar like this.props.skillsref.....

Comment: and probably if you use the latest version of react, you have to look about  React.createRef()

Comment: @MatteoAngelotti The problem with that is that I have to add like 7 props to my navbar, isn't there a simpeler way? And it's not working, just tried parsing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:
You have to define this in your app class

```
introref =React.createRef()
timelineref = React.createRef()
projectsref = React.createRef()
skillsref = React.createRef()
certifref = React.createRef()
downloadref = React.createRef()
contactref = React.createRef()
```

and use like this:

```
 <Introduction ref={this.introref} />
    <Timeline ref={this.timelineref} />
    <Projects ref={this.projectsref} />
    <Skills ref={ this.skillsref} />
    <Certificates ref={this.certifref} />
    <Download ref={this.downloadref } />
    <Contact ref={this.contactref} />
```

and yes you have to crate props in your NavBar:

```
<Navbar
  introref={this.introref}
  timelineref={this.timelineref}
  projectsref={this.projectsref}
  skillsref={this.skillsref}
  certifref={this.certifref}
  downloadref={this.downloadref } 
  contactref{this.contactref}
/>
```

And inside NavBar you have to use like this:

```
const { introref,timelineref,projectsref,skillsref,certifref,downloadref,contactref } = this.props
```

and you can us the ref like call

```
introref.current
timelineref.current
```

so in your code something like:

```
<Navitem dName={"Skills"} url={"skills"} onClick={() => scrollToComponent(skillsref.current, { duration: 1600 })} />
```

I hope it will work

Comment: What is ```.current``` For? I tried applying it like you said but still don't work, not errors

Comment: current give you access at your element ... you can find documentation in React.CreateRef .... and you can try to see wath is give you back in console.log(skillsref.current)....

Comment: I added a console.log() and it works now. I just get the error that I shouldn't parse refs

Comment: But for some reasons all the buttons now redirect to the same component

Comment: sorry but as I told you I'm new in React also... i finded a solution like this in my code ...i had to use a props of comp A in comB and I did like i said you.... I used myVar.current.querySelector(`[name=${name}]`) to get name props of A in B